# How to set titleForHeaderInSection manually

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, plist, title

I load data from plist to uitableview like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *path = [[documentPaths lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"];

    NSMutableDictionary *resultDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *resultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *myDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];


    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"purpleKey"])
    {
        NSArray *purple = [myDict objectForKey:@"Purple"];
        [resultArray addObject:@"Purple"];
        [resultDic setValue:purple forKey:@"Purple"];
    }
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"orangeKey"])
    {
        NSArray *orange = [myDict objectForKey:@"Orange"];
        [resultArray addObject:@"Orange"];
        [resultDic setValue:orange forKey:@"Orange"];
    }


    self.tableData = resultDic;
    self.sectionsTitle = resultArray;

}
```

titleForHeaderInSection

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
   return [sectionsTitle objectAtIndex:section];
}
```

my plist structure

[image]

**My question is: 
How can I manually set title for Purple header and Orange header without to changing names in plist file?
like this: Purple = Category 1, Orange = Category 2**

EDIT

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
   return sectionsTitle.count;
}


- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
   return [sectionsTitle objectAtIndex:section];
}



- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    int num = [[tableData objectForKey:[sectionsTitle objectAtIndex:section]] count];

    if (num > 3) {
        num = 3;
    }

    return num;
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSDictionary *dict = [[tableData objectForKey:[sectionsTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 1; 
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:11]; 
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", [dict objectForKey:@"Name"], [dict objectForKey:@"Address"]];

    if ([dict objectForKey:@"Address"] == (NULL)) {
        //do nothing
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean when the app is running, you can change the titles, or you just want to change it during development to a different value?

Comment: during development to a different value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the look of your code, the section headers are coming from `resultsArray`, which you are populating with the constant strings Orange and Purple.

You can just put different constant strings into that array, unless I'm missing something.

So, instead of

```
[resultArray addObject:@"Orange"];
```

Use

```
[resultArray addObject:@"Category 1"];
```

Comment: Yes, it changes header, but after that category is empty

Comment: Well, you must be using the resultArray or self.sectionTitles somewhere else, as a key for a dictionary or something. Add a new array which is just used for the titles, and keep the original one for the keys.

Comment: I added more code to question, can you help me find what I need to change?

Comment: It's like I guessed - sectionTitles is doing double duty, holding keys and section titles. You should create a new property, for readability I guess it should be called sectionKeys, this would hold your orange, purple etc and would be used everywhere you are currently using sectionTitles, except for where you actually want section titles.

Comment: Alternatively, restructure your data do you have one array for all your data. Each entry in the array is a dictionary holding a section name and the data for that section. Seems cleaner.

Comment: I have about 5000 entries in my plist, restructuring is too difficult. Where I need to keep sectionTitles to leave showing my rows?